Laravel - Access information with nested validation request
I want to access information within nested validation array to do a custom validation, here is my code:
return [
...,
'amount' => ['nullable', 'numeric'],
'currency_id' => ['nullable', 'integer', Rule::in($allowedCurrencyIds)],
'details' => ['nullable'],
'details.*.product_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:products,id'],
'details.*.product_collection_id' => [
   'nullable',
   'integer',
   'exists:product_collections,id',
   new ProductAndCollectionValidator($this->details.*.->product_id, $this->details->product_collection_id)
],
...
]

As you can see I want to access the product id and the product collection id with details.* to send to the custom validatior ProductAndCollectionValidator. And I need to concider that product_collection_id might be null sometimes. And that is the first step.
Second step I want to make sure that there are no duplicate product_id and product_collection_id the the details array
How can I do that?

you can use Laravel's custom validation rules and validation closures. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#using-closures. Try this on your validator:
return [
    // Other validation rules...
    'details.*.product_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:products,id'],
    'details.*.product_collection_id' => [
        'nullable',
        'integer',
        'exists:product_collections,id',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            // Accessing nested values within details array
            $productId = $this->input('details')[$this->getIndexFromAttribute($attribute)]['product_id'];
            // Custom validation logic using ProductAndCollectionValidator
            $validator = new ProductAndCollectionValidator($productId, $value);
            if (!$validator->passes()) {
                $fail($validator->message());
            }
        }
    ],
    'details' => ['nullable', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        // Custom validation rule to check for duplicates
        $uniqueDetails = collect($value)->unique(function ($detail) {
            return $detail['product_id'] . '-' . $detail['product_collection_id'];
        });
        if ($uniqueDetails->count() !== count($value)) {
            $fail('Duplicate product_id and product_collection_id combinations found.');
        }
    }],
];


function getIndexFromAttribute($attribute)
{
    return explode('.', str_replace(['[*]', '*'], ['.', ''], $attribute))[1];
}

Let me know. Cheers.

Here are 2 solutions. I didn't tested. Please let me know if there is an error.

You could create a single custom rule for data array:

Request:
return [
    ...,
    'amount' => ['nullable', 'numeric'],
    'currency_id' => ['nullable', 'integer', Rule::in($allowedCurrencyIds)],
    'details' => ['nullable', 'array', new ArrayUniqueItems(['product_id', 'product_collection_id'])],
    'details.*.product_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:products,id'],
    'details.*.product_collection_id' => ['nullable', 'integer', 'exists:product_collections,id'],
    ...
];

Rule:
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;

class ArrayUniqueItems implements ValidationRule
{
    public function __construct(private arrray $keys) {}

    public function __invoke($attribute, $value, $fail): void
    {
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            collect(collect($value)->duplicates($key))
                ->each(fn ($item, $index) => $fail(
                    "$attribute.$index.product_id", 
                    "Duplicate $key"),
                );
        }
    }
}


You could create a custom rule data items:

Request:
return [
    ...,
    'amount' => ['nullable', 'numeric'],
    'currency_id' => ['nullable', 'integer', Rule::in($allowedCurrencyIds)],
    'details' => ['nullable', 'array'],
    'details.*.product_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:products,id', new UniqueInArray('product_id')],
    'details.*.product_collection_id' => ['nullable', 'integer', 'exists:product_collections,id'],
    ...
];

Rule:
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;

class UniqueInArray implements ValidationRule, DataAwareRule
{
    /**
     * All of the data under validation.
     *
     * @var array<string, mixed>
     */
    protected $data = [];

    public function __invoke($attribute, $value, $fail): void
    {
        // This part is not safe but gives an idea to find the index
        $root = explode('.', $attribute)[0];
        $index = (int) explode('.', $attribute)[1];
        $key = explode('.', $attribute)[2];

        $duplicates = collect($this->data[$root] ?? [])->duplicates($key);

        if (array_key_exists($index, $duplicates)) {
            $fail($attribute, "Duplicate $key");
        }
    
    }

     /**
     * Set the data under validation.
     *
     * @param  array<string, mixed>  $data
     */
    public function setData(array $data): static
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }
}

